# continuous query in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, streaming, continuous

I have a spatio-temporal database in Postgresql that is continuously updates. I was wondering if there is a technique for continuous query in this database? for example I have temperature data that updates every minute in the database for specific area. I want to perform aggregate queries to show me the temperature every hour (aggregated value).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can't continuously update query, but you can receive notification on events of importance and reissue your query.

Comment: You mean by LISTEN/NOTIFY techniques? Yes but can I perform other functions (like aggregation) using the information from notifications?

Comment: That's the first part of the answer ;-) So you can either get updated data and do the aggregation on client side or reissue the original query. Details depend on your particular tasks.

Answer (score 0):

There are plugins like PipelineDB that may be able to help you

Answer (score 0):

There is an possibility to have an update/insert/delete trigger, which will call NOTIFY with anything you want. For example, result of aggregated data. Have on mind, there are two types of triggers. One see data after update in table happens and another is able to see data before change happens.

One have to choose how complex business logic is in DB (i.e. triggers with business logic, which at the end sends nice data using NOTIFY to LISTEN-ing counterpart in application). Personally I have used in one project to send directly info about change to backend, which than triggered normal queries if needed. This can be also done using something like "streaming database changes". In larger scale, you can make use of [Debezium](https://debezium.io/), stream everything into app with kafka in path if needed.

Oracle database have something you are searching for. It is called [Continuous Query Notification](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADFNS/adfns_cqn.htm#ADFNS018).

There is also [RethinkDb](https://rethinkdb.com/), which perfectly suits your need. Have a look at ist current development and maturiny and i can sui to your project perhaps.